# Getting "Stream is not Readable" error when trying to get RAW body from Paddle request - NextJS

Tags: next.js, payment, paddle

I am trying to verify a Paddle webhook by creating a singled payload as described on this page:
https://developer.paddle.com/webhooks/signature-verification

The issue is that every time I try to get a RAW body from the request, I am getting the following error:

> BACKEND: 2023-12-28T18:38:08.384Z error: An error occurred ->InternalServerError: stream is not readable

Here is my code:

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import crud from "../../crudWrapper";
import logger from "../../logger";
import { StatusCodes } from "http-status-codes";
import { authOptions } from "../../auth/[...nextauth]";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";

let getRawBody = require('raw-body')

/**
 * POST Function to call a pecific webhook
 * @param req - Next API route request object
 * @param res - Next API route response
 */
const postFunc = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
    console.log(session)
    try {
        if (!req.body) return res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).json({ error: "No request body found" })
        // Step 1. Pare PADDLE Header (i.e., paddle-signature)
        const paddleSignature = req.headers['paddle-signature'];
        const timeStamp = (paddleSignature as string).split(';')[0].split('=')[1]
        const h1 = (paddleSignature as string).split(';')[1].split('=')[1]

        // Step 2. Create a SIGNED PAYLOAD
        const rawBody = await getRawBody(req);
        const data = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(rawBody).toString('utf8'));
        const signedPayload = timeStamp + ':' + rawBody;

        switch (req.body.event_type) {
            case "transaction.completed":
                logger.info('User ' + session.user.email + " has successfully completed a transaction!")
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ success: true });
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error("An error occurred ->" + e);
        return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
            status: StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            message: e.message,
        });
    }
};

export default crud(null, postFunc, null, null);
```

Can someone please help me out, what am I doing wrong here?